# Why does my page look different when resizing window than in Chrome mobile viewer?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make my webpage responsive, but I'm confused as to which view is correct. When I open it in chrome normally and resize the window it looks normal (image 1). But when I inspect element and view the page in the mobile viewer, it looks completely different (image 2). Which one is correct?

[Chrome resized - Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbBJh.png)

[Chrome mobile viewer - Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK7SF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. Use the inspector by pressing `CTRL + SHIFT + C` (`cmd + shift + c` on macs) and hover/click on the element you want more info for. This will help you find out what's happening at the different viewport widths.

You can also right click on the element and click `Inspect Element`

Also, make sure your html has the following tag:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I completely forgot to add that meta tag in, I usually remember that but I somehow forgot this time.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an element that is overflowing on the y-axis. making the page wider. since you probably have the navbar 100% width and flex aligned it will look like this. check if there are no elements overflowing using the inspector.